# numpy array sum function

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sum

Let's say I have two one dimensional arrays, a and b, of length say n+1 and m+1.

I want c to be the an array of the same length as b, with elements equal to the sine of the sum of all a elements to the power b. Written in pseudo code below.

```
c = sum(sine(a[0:n] ** b[0])), sum(sine(a[0:n] ** b[1])),
  ... sum(sine(a[0:n] ** b[m])))
```

Is there a way I can accomplish this without using loops?

(Somewhat inexperienced in programming, hope my question makes sense.)

a function something ala this:

```
def function(a, b):
    c = np.sum(np.sin(a ** b))
    return c
```

Comment: You probably mean `a` and `b` have length `n`...

Comment: In your edit, the `sin(..)` is the inner function. Do you want the sine of the sum or the sum of the sines?

Comment: oh, I want sum of the sines, sorry for not being precise.. the problem I want to solve is different from this, I tried making a much simplified version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to sum the sines, you can first construct an *m×n*-matrix by using:

```
a.reshape(-1,1) ** b
```

Next we can calculate the `sin` of all these powers with `np.sin(..)`:

```
np.sin(a.reshape(-1,1) ** b)
```

If we now want to sum over these `sin`s, we can use `np.sum(..)` over the first axis:

```
np.sum(np.sin(a.reshape(-1,1) ** b),axis=0)
```

If `a = [0,1,...,9]` and `b = [0,1]` we obtain:

```
>>> a = np.arange(10)
>>> b = np.arange(2)
>>> np.sum(np.sin(a.reshape(-1,1) ** b),axis=0)
array([ 8.41470985,  1.95520948])
```

Since `sin(0**0)+sin(1**0)+sin(2**0)+...+sin(9**0) = 10*sin(1) = 10*0.8414709848078965`, the first value is correct. For the second one, this is equal to `sin(0**1)+sin(1**1)+sin(2**1)+...+sin(9**1) = sin(0)+sin(1)+...+sin(8)+sin(9)`. This is - according to [*WolframAlpha*](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+of+sin(i)+for+i+from+0+to+9) indeed `1.95520`.

Comment: Oh yes, this seems to be exactly what I wanted.. its complexity is however a couple of level deeper than I'm used to, so I'm gonna have to play around with it some.. thanks alot!

Answer (score 2):

You can vectorize it with numpy broadcasting:

```
np.sin(np.sum(a ** b[:,None], axis=1))
```

---

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(4)
b = np.arange(3)

np.sin(np.sum(a ** b[:,None], axis=1))
#array([-0.7568025 , -0.2794155 ,  0.99060736])

np.sin(np.sum(a ** b[0]))
#-0.7568024953079282

np.sin(np.sum(a ** b[1]))
#-0.27941549819892586
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks very interesting!